# Looking for a network switch with multi network management capabilities, load balancing and web management

Tags: networking, switch, firewall

This is my first post in this forum, I posted this in another stackexchange forum and was redirected here.

I am looking for a network switch that provides a few features:

1 - Manage multiple network ranges - I have 2 public /27 ranges, which I would like to manage from the switch, for example what IP addresses go to each server. I would also like the switch to be able to handle one or multiple private network ranges, and be able to tell the switch that public IP X.X.X.X should be mapped to a server which is using private IP Y.Y.Y.Y

2 - Web management - This is a must. The switch will be at a datacenter, so I need a way to manage it, like I would do with an IPMI interface on a server. I would like to do all configuration of the switch from that web interface. It would be great if the switch's web interface would allow me to see bandwidth and other useful information regarding network usage from each of the servers.

3 - Load balancing - I would like the switch to be able to balance traffic between multiple servers, for example round robin between 3 private IP addresses requests that come for a give public IP address. Level 2 load balancing would be best.

4 - Firewall - I would like to be able to forward all requests to a given IP to a specific server, but I would like to have the option to block everything or leave just a specific port open at the switch level. I would be able to manage individual server's firewalls but also have the ability to control this from the switch for a given server.

The idea is to be able to have the switch passthrough requests to public IP addresses if I want a server to have its network card configured with a public IP address, but also be able to configure a server with a private IP address and configure the switch to forward requests from one IP to another.

Is this even possible? Or should I be approaching this in a different way?

I am looking for any tips from people who have used equipments that do this, as I don't have experience with these sort of equipments. Even though I know this is not for opinion based answers, if anyone has experience with different brands and can shed some light into what works better, that would be great.

I am not looking for a specific brand, so Juniper, Cisco, FS, or any brand would be an option.

For example, I like this one but I am unsure if it has all the features I am looking for, still trying to determine from the documentation: https://www.fs.com/products/72945.html

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an [L3 Switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_switch#Layer_3_switching), which is really just a router with the ports/bandwidth of a large switch. Most "Managed Switches" provide the features you're looking for, except that a firewall is often its own device or implemented in the router. (Do you need to put a firewall between devices on your private network?)

Comment: @Romen I would like the ability to use the firewall for requests to some IPs or servers, and not others. If I could get the switch to do that, I would avoid a second physical device, wasting precious rack space :) Can you suggest a brand / model (if you know any) that checks all the points?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the topology, do you want to use the firewall in the usual way where it blocks *incoming* requests (from the WAN) to devices on your LAN? Or something else like blocking *outgoing* requests from your LAN or requests between devices on the same LAN? If you want a typical firewall that handles port forwarding and blocks other incoming requests from WAN, a switch wouldn't be used for that. Like I mentioned already, an "L3 switch" is actually a router with a bunch of ports, but they're often called switches because they look like a regular L2 switch.

Comment: @Romen I am more worried about incoming than outgoing traffic. Nonetheless, both would be better for future proofing things. Do you mean that a L2 switch would porbably have that builtin, while L3 wouldn't? In that case, I would rather get myself an L2 one. Or did I understand you incorrectly?

Comment: @Romen thank you very much about that link, it was an interesting read. I am not a network expert, and I was not aware of the Layer differences. From your last response, I understand that I should probably aim for a router instead of a switch, if I need load balancing and firewall features. Once again, and I know this is not made for suggestions, but can you point me to something that would fir these requirements?

Comment: Sorry for deleting that comment just now. ([OSI model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) link for posterity.) I was about to rewrite my comment saying exactly that: Switches do not normally provide fully featured firewalls or load balancing because that is the job of a router. The switch's primary purpose is to be a high bandwidth intersection for your LAN. An L3 switch takes that device a step further by providing software features like you're asking for, but a router is more suited to load balancing and firewall functions specifically.

Comment: I'm not really knowledgeable in the higher end switch/router options out there. I do know that load balancing (i.e. routing HTTP requests to a specific server) requires a switch/router that can access L4 (Transport Layer) in order to determine which TCP session the packets belong to. I am only familiar with some L2 and L3 devices with *most* of the requirements you stated. Maybe you should consider setting up a server running a router OS? At a certain tier like L3 or Managed, these networking products basically are servers in custom "switch" housing.

Comment: @Romen I know I can use pfSense or something similar for routing and firewall purposes. I am still trying to get around my head how I would manage that in a datacenter environment. Physically, how would I connect that to all the servers below? Or are you referring to having a physical switch and installing pfsense or another into that? Is this even feasible?

Comment: The pfSense device really only needs a pair of network interfaces, for WAN and LAN, any extras would either be for additional throughput, a 2nd ISP, or redundancy of some kind. You would still need a switch plugged into the LAN port on the pfSense router, unless the server hardware has that built in (which you *can* buy). Remote management would be possible from either LAN or WAN, depending on how you set it up.

Comment: @Romen that was exactly what I had in mind. My main concern was trying to squeeze all of that into 1U, without having 1U with a pfSense server and another 1U for a switch underneath it, but I get your point. I was hoping for a 2 in 1 solution, buying a router / switch equipment with something similar to pfsense inside or the ability to install that into the equipment.

Comment: Well the big networking brands should have some 1U "switches" (that are really servers/routers) that do what you need. You can also buy [official pfSense hardware](https://www.pfsense.org/products/), they look like they only come with 4 ports though. Lastly, you may be able to find a 1U server with an ethernet switch built into the chassis. Although, most people would settle for 2U to fit a switch & router because it's easier to replace just the switch, or just the router, with that kind of setup.